# Adding a "calculated field" in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a raw table in bigquery, and I want to add a "conditional"/"calculated" column based on a given value, saying something like:

```
CASE
  WHEN `columnA`="valueX" THEN `columnB`
  ELSE NULL
AS `valueX`
```

The problem is that I can't just say `SELECT *, CASE...`, since then I must do `GROUP BY` over all of the columns.
Is there a simple way to create a "calculated" column like that ? Maybe using some UDF and views "tricks" ?

Input example:
[image]

Output example:
[image]
Thanks In advance,
Shushu

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Example added, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE
    WHEN columnA='valueX' THEN columnB
    ELSE NULL
  END AS valueX
FROM
```

Comment: Well, it works...  Soo strange, since as you can see in the question, this is what I tried (at least what I thought I tried), and got an error saying I must `GROUP BY` all of the fields...

Comment: Looking in more details  - i think you were missing `END` to close `CASE`

Comment: Thanks. No it wasn't it. I found out that I while I wrote in the question the `CASE` option, when checking I used:
```MAX(IF(`feature_2_name` = 'test4',
      `feature_2_value`,
      NULL)) AS `test4`
```
Which then gave an error: "Star expansion expression references column event_name which is neither grouped nor aggregated"

Comment: And it is reasonable, since MAX is aggregation, which changes the whole SELECT. 10x again.